# How do I change cell data (In mat-table) text to white on whole row when row active selected?

Tags: css, angular

I want to change the text color when my row is active selected. I have managed to change the background color on the row but how do i find the text in the cells?

I am thinking that I could do it like the same way, I did the highlight method but what to target for hitting the row cell text?

**My HTML:**

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.containerNo}"
                (click)="highlight(row)"
                (click)="openCentred(content)">

</mat-row>
```

**My TS**

```
selectedRowIndex: number = -1;

    highlight(row) {
        this.selectedRowIndex = row.containerNo;
    }
```

**My CSS**

```
.highlight  {
    background:#286090; /* darkblue */

  }
```

Any ideas how to change the text color on the row when selected?

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `row.id` instead of `row.containerNo`.

And to change the text colour, you need to target the cell itself. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table-uv5aup) working SlackBlitz.